# Combining Linq expressions using EFCore 3.0

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-3.0

I have a function doing a complicated Where query on my db context and then applies another transformation passed to it:

```
static IQueryable<T> Query<T>(Func<IQueryable<ServicesData>, IQueryable<T>> f, string path1 = null, string path2 = null, string path3 = null, string path4 = null, string path5 = null) {
    try {
        using (var dbc = new MyDbContext() ) {
            var res = dbc.ServicesData
                .Where(sd =>
                    (path1 == null || (path1.Contains("%") || path1.Contains("_") ? EF.Functions.Like(sd.Path1, path1) : sd.Path1 == path1))
                    && (path2 == null || (path2.Contains("%") || path2.Contains("_") ? EF.Functions.Like(sd.Path2, path2) : sd.Path2 == path2))
                    && (path3 == null || (path3.Contains("%") || path3.Contains("_") ? EF.Functions.Like(sd.Path3, path3) : sd.Path3 == path3))
                    && (path4 == null || (path4.Contains("%") || path4.Contains("_") ? EF.Functions.Like(sd.Path4, path4) : sd.Path4 == path4))
                    && (path5 == null || (path5.Contains("%") || path5.Contains("_") ? EF.Functions.Like(sd.Path5, path5) : sd.Path5 == path5)));

            return f(res.ToList().AsQueryable());
            //return f(res).ToList().AsQueryable(); 
        }
    } catch (Exception ex_) {
        return VList<T>.Empty.AsQueryable();
    }
}
```

This is used ie like this:

```
IQueryable<int> Int1InLastHour(IQueryable<ServicesData> input) {
    var lastHour = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddHours(-1).ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();
    return input
     .Where(v => (v.Time <= lastHour) && (v.Int1 is object))
     .Select(v => v.Int1.Value);
}

var lastHourProcessTime = Query(Int1InLastHour, "Publisher", "%", "ItemProcessTime").Sum();
```

This works, however since I call `res.ToList()` *before* calling `f` the linq in `f` is done in memory  and not on the DB SQL

If I try to replace `f(res.ToList().AsQueryable())` with `f(res).ToList().AsQueryable()` I get an exception:

> {"Processing of the LINQ expression '[EntityShaperExpression][ServicesData]' by 'RelationalProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor' failed. This may indicate either a bug or a limitation in EF Core. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101433 for more detailed information."}

Is there any way for me to solve this ? can I somehow pass the query (`Func<IQueryable<ServicesData>, IQueryable<T>>`) and then combine it to the query in `Query` before excecuting it on the dbc ?

Comment: Why not process your null checks and % test outside the query and build a simple query with no conditional operators in it? You don't need the DB to decide whether path1 contains a % character.

Comment: Also why do you pass a Func in to apply instead of just applying it outside. `q(Query("Publisher", "%", "Ping")` or make it an extension method on `IQueryable` so you can do `Query(...).q()`.

Comment: But the real issue is that `KeyValuePair.Create` isn't going to translate to SQL. Just return an anonymous type with the fields you want and do that piece client-side.

Comment: You mean convert them to predicate before passing them to Where ? I don't think that will work but anyway that is not what my question is about

Comment: The whole point is about passing the Func .. I will be calling Query from different places with different `f` functions

Comment: Well you can't pass functions that don't translate to SQL and expect them to work. Also what time do you expect `DateTimeOffset.Now` to be on the SQL server (if you could even do that)?

Comment: I changed the example query above to one that should translate to SQL - still no luck

Answer (score 1):

A few issues. You can split the querying to break down your results, but the scope of your DbContext needs to be at the outermost point of the chain, not inside the inner-most:

This here:

```
static IQueryable<T> Query<T>(Func<IQueryable<ServicesData>, IQueryable<T>> f, string path1 = null, string path2 = null, string path3 = null, string path4 = null, string path5 = null) {
    try {
        using (var dbc = new MyDbContext() ) { // DbContext should not be scoped here...
            var res = dbc.ServicesData
```

As the simplest re-factor:

```
static IQueryable<T> Query<T>(MyDbContext dbc, Func<IQueryable<ServicesData>, IQueryable<T>> f, string path1 = null, string path2 = null, string path3 = null, string path4 = null, string path5 = null) {
    try 
    {
        var res = dbc.ServicesData.AsQueryable();
        if(path1 != null)
           if(path1.Contains("%") || path1.Contains("_"))
               res = res.Where(EF.Functions.Like(sd.Path1, path1));
           else
               res = res.Where(sd.Path1 == path1);
        // Repeat for Path 2 - 5 ....

        return f(res);
    } 
    catch (Exception ex_) 
    {
        return VList<T>.Empty.AsQueryable();
    }
}
```

Firstly, we pass in the DbContext. If the context is scoped here, the list must be materialized before being returned. The goal is to allow callers to further reduce the expression before executing the list. This means the DbContext needs to be scoped outside of this initial generation and passed in. With IoC containers managing lifetime scope you can bypass this if the DbContext is injected and scoped to a Request or common lifetime scope.

The next improvement suggestion is to move the conditional checks for the parameters out of the Linq and into regular conditions so that the Like / Equals check will only be added if the condition was provided. This will result in simpler, faster SQL being run on the server.

So the end result would look something like:

```
using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext())
{
   var lastHourProcessTime = Query(dbContext, Int1InLastHour, "Publisher", "%", "ItemProcessTime").Sum();
}
```

I sort of get where you're trying to go here, but abstracting expressions from EF is bound to lead to confusing code and still prone to limitations and bugs. IMO keeping it simpler generally leads to less issues, but give this a go and see if it gets you closer.

Comment: useful suggestions regarding the conditional checks thanks! however that and moving the db context outside does not change anything regarding `f(res).ToList().AsQueryable()`, that is still done in the same way at the same place so will have the same issue. Or am I confused ?

Comment: No, by moving the context out, the execution should be able to be deferred, you should be able to avoid needing the .ToList(). I see I missed the `f()` wrapper in my re-factored example. I'll correct that.   Since the function returns `IQueryable`, just return `f(res)` without the `ToList`.  The only other thing might be the outer `&& v.Int1 is object`, would `&& v.Int1.HasValue` be suitable? I'm not sure if the former can be translated into SQL.

Comment: the `is object` is just for checking "is not null" .. I now get what you're doing, I may have to go that way though not ideal, as it means repeating the `using` statement/block in many places

Comment: If you are using an IoC container like Unity or Autofac you can register the Context as a dependency. If it is lifetime scoped to the web request (assuming MVC) then you can avoid needing the using blocks unless you want more granular control over a context scope.

Comment: do you think that can that be done with asp.net core build in dependency injections ? I'm not familiar with Uniti/Autofac

Comment: Yes, register it as "Scoped" and it will be bound as a single reference per request.